# One distribution of SWT-based application for 32 and 64bit environments

Tags: swt, distribution, 32bit-64bit

I want to have the same distribution of SWT-based application for Windows 32 and 64bit environments. Is it at all possible?

**UPD**: I want to have a single jar dependency, that can be used both on Windows 32 and 64bit bit environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can not have two different target environments i.e. x32 and x64, with the plain vanilla version of SWT (i.e. the unmodified version).

If you are willing to change the SWT code itself then theoretically it is possible to load different versions of DLL as per the target environment. But you might introduce some bugs and have to keep your version updated with the new releases and bug fixes (that are released by eclipse).

Also there is another way of having two different set of jars **(which you don't want)**. And depending on the architecture ( x32 or x64) include the respective SWT jar in the class path.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; see Eclipse's [SWT deployment guide](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/jws/) for example. Note that it's not just a 32-bit vs 64-bit problem, you must also take into account different platforms (Windows, OS X, Linux).

Comment: Yes, obviously it can be deployed using Java Web Start. However, I would like to have a non-JNLP solution.

Comment: Ah. In that case, I'd say just bundle the SWT libraries for all the platforms you want to support, and configure the launcher script to pick the right one based on the computer it's launched on.